# I've installed a Haste Mod, although

Tags: azerothcore

So I'm using AzerothCore, and I recently just installed a Haste Mod, it's working, but not functioning properly, the Haste Mod I had to install manually due to times changing and codes changing, although now.

My issue is that even though I get 0.00 after I reached a certain amount of haste, it is too fast & proccs don't work, example: Shadowmourne weapon effect...

Sometimes I'm hitting up to 80 times pr game tick, and it varies for 50-80, I want to ask you guys, is it possible to make it locked to a certain amount of attack counts? Both Melee and Ranged, due to sound glitching out also, *sometimes sound disappears until I stop attacking*, This is unlike any haste mod I ever tested, whether it be a live server or a test server...

The Hastemod is the following:

```
PLAYER.CPP
hasteMod = 2.9;

/* hastemod
if (haveOffhandWeapon())
if (getAttackTimer(OFF_ATTACK) < ATTACK_DISPLAY_DELAY)
setAttackTimer(OFF_ATTACK, ATTACK_DISPLAY_DELAY);
*/

/* hastemod
if (getAttackTimer(BASE_ATTACK) < ATTACK_DISPLAY_DELAY)
setAttackTimer(BASE_ATTACK, ATTACK_DISPLAY_DELAY);
*/

// hastemod begins
void Player::SetAttackTime(WeaponAttackType att, uint32 val) {
    switch(att) {
        case BASE_ATTACK:
        ApplyHasteMod(m_baseRatingValue[CR_HASTE_MELEE],BASE_ATTACK,CR_HASTE_MELEE, val);
        break;

        case OFF_ATTACK:
        ApplyHasteMod(m_baseRatingValue[CR_HASTE_MELEE],OFF_ATTACK,CR_HASTE_MELEE, val);
        break;
        case RANGED_ATTACK:
        ApplyHasteMod(m_baseRatingValue[CR_HASTE_RANGED],RANGED_ATTACK,CR_HASTE_RANGED, val);
        break;

        default:
        SetFloatValue(UNIT_FIELD_BASEATTACKTIME+att,val*m_modAttackSpeedPct[att]);
    }
}

void Player::ApplyHasteMod(int16 val, uint32 att, CombatRating cr, float speed) {
    float atkSpd = speed * (( 100.0f - ((val / 32.789989f) * hasteMod)  ) / 100.0f );
    if (atkSpd < 0) atkSpd = 0;
SetFloatValue(UNIT_FIELD_BASEATTACKTIME+att, atkSpd);
}

// hastemod ends

 void Player::ApplyRatingMod(CombatRating cr, int32 value, bool apply)
 {
     m_baseRatingValue[cr]+=(apply ? value : -value);
   // explicit affected values
   switch (cr)
   {
       case CR_HASTE_MELEE:
       {
            Item * mainhand = m_items[EQUIPMENT_SLOT_MAINHAND];
            Item * offhand = m_items[EQUIPMENT_SLOT_OFFHAND];
            float speed1 = mainhand ? (float)mainhand->GetTemplate()->Delay : 2000.0f;
            float speed2 = offhand ? (float)offhand->GetTemplate()->Delay : 2000.0f;

            ApplyHasteMod(m_baseRatingValue[cr], BASE_ATTACK, cr, speed1);
            ApplyHasteMod(m_baseRatingValue[cr], OFF_ATTACK, cr, speed2);

            float RatingChange = value / value;
            (RatingChange = 0) ? ApplyPercentModFloatVar(m_modAttackSpeedPct[BASE_ATTACK], RatingChange, !apply) : ApplyPercentModFloatVar(m_modAttackSpeedPct[BASE_ATTACK], -RatingChange, apply);
            (RatingChange = 0) ? ApplyPercentModFloatVar(m_modAttackSpeedPct[OFF_ATTACK], RatingChange, !apply) : ApplyPercentModFloatVar(m_modAttackSpeedPct[OFF_ATTACK], -RatingChange, apply);
             break;
         }
         case CR_HASTE_RANGED:
         {
            Item * ranged = m_items[EQUIPMENT_SLOT_RANGED];
            float speed = ranged ? (float)ranged->GetTemplate()->Delay : 2000.0f;
            ApplyHasteMod(m_baseRatingValue[cr], RANGED_ATTACK, cr, speed);
            float RatingChange = value / value;
            (RatingChange = 0) ? ApplyPercentModFloatVar(m_modAttackSpeedPct[RANGED_ATTACK], RatingChange, !apply) : ApplyPercentModFloatVar(m_modAttackSpeedPct[RANGED_ATTACK], -RatingChange, apply);
             break;
         }
         case CR_HASTE_SPELL:
         {
            ApplyHasteMod(m_baseRatingValue[cr], CR_HASTE_SPELL-1, cr, 1.0f);
             break;
         }
         default:

PLAYER.H


        float hasteMod;
        public:

        float GetHasteMod() const { return hasteMod; }
        void SetHasteMod(float val) { hasteMod = val; }
        void ApplyHasteMod(int16 val, uint32 att, CombatRating cr, float speed);
        void SetAttackTime(WeaponAttackType att, uint32 val);

STATSYSTEM.CPP

 void Player::CalculateMinMaxDamage(WeaponAttackType attType, bool normalized, bool addTotalPct, float& min_damage, float& max_damage)
 {
     UnitMods unitMod;
    Item *Weapon = NULL;

     switch (attType)
     {
         case BASE_ATTACK:
         default:
            Weapon = m_items[EQUIPMENT_SLOT_MAINHAND];
             unitMod = UNIT_MOD_DAMAGE_MAINHAND;
             break;
         case OFF_ATTACK:
            Weapon = m_items[EQUIPMENT_SLOT_OFFHAND];
             unitMod = UNIT_MOD_DAMAGE_OFFHAND;
             break;
         case RANGED_ATTACK:
            Weapon = m_items[EQUIPMENT_SLOT_RANGED];
             unitMod = UNIT_MOD_DAMAGE_RANGED;
             break;
     }


    float wep_speed   =(!Weapon) ? 2200.00f : Weapon->GetTemplate()->Delay;
    float base_value  = GetModifierValue(unitMod, BASE_VALUE) + GetTotalAttackPowerValue(attType)/ 14.0f  (wep_speed/1000.00f);
    float att_speed   = GetAPMultiplier(attType,normalized);
    float base_pct    = GetModifierValue(unitMod, BASE_PCT);    
    float total_value = GetModifierValue(unitMod, TOTAL_VALUE);
    float total_pct   = addTotalPct ? GetModifierValue(unitMod, TOTAL_PCT) : 1.0f;

     float weapon_mindamage = GetWeaponDamageRange(attType, MINDAMAGE);
     float weapon_maxdamage = GetWeaponDamageRange(attType, MAXDAMAGE);


         if (lvl > 60)
             lvl = 60;

        weapon_mindamage = lvl*3.0f*wep_speed/1000;
        weapon_maxdamage = lvl*5.0f*wep_speed/1000;
     }
     else if (!CanUseAttackType(attType))      //check if player not in form but still can't use (disarm case)
     {
```

I would love if you guys have heard or seen anything like this before, and know what to do, I've spent the last 3 days, trying to figure it out... I know it's possible, just don't know how, or if it's even possible with this hastemod.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid modifying the main core's files (e.g. `Player.cpp`, `Player.h`, etc..) but create a real (separate) module for your custom changes:

http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Create-a-Module

If you need to implement new hooks, then you should send a PR to the main repo. So your core codebase will always be clean (without custom changes).

Comment: Hey thanks for the input, I will look into the Create a Module post, and see how it works. I tried to apply the patch with git apply, although it was outdated, so I tried to implement it manually, it did what it were supposed to, but seemingly attacking too fast even for reaching the cap. I'll take your Answer into consideration and attempt making it into a module!

Comment: Patching the core is a bad practice and Modules were created in AzerothCore in order to avoid them ;)