# Remove 5 second mana regen rule Azerothcore

Tags: azerothcore

I am looking to remove the 5 second rule in the code. I see a bunch of mana regen handles inside `Player.cpp` but i am not sure which to remove or change.

The 5 second rule is a timer to where when you do not cast a spell for 5 seconds you start to regen mana faster.

Thank you

Comment: Editing core files like `Player.cpp` is not recommended, you can read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59609950/3497671

Answer (score 0):

just remove them all, recompile, test, if it works, then remove only half of them, recompile, test etc...